# Simplification problem using trigs

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

given

```
f1 = Sin[x]/Sqrt[2 + Sin[2 x]]
f2 = (Cos[x]-Cos[3 x]+4 Sin[x])/(2 (2+Sin[2 x])^(3/2))
```

These are same for all x.

```
Simplify[f1 == f2]
(* True *)
```

But how to simplify `f2` directly to becomes `f1`?  As `Simplify[f2]` and `FullSimplify[f2]` both do nothing. It is clear the leaf size of `f1` is less than `f2`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Also  `TrigReduce[f2]` also did not do it.

Any tricks to try? And why did not Simplify/FullSimplify do it automatically? Should it have been able to do it?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.1

Comment: `FullSimplify[TrigToExp @ f2]`?

Comment: @MarcoB thanks. I did not think of trying this one. Do you think Mathematica's Simpify or FullSimplify or TrigReduce should have done it automatically?

Comment: `f2 // TrigExpand // Simplify`

Comment: @Syed another nice workaround. But my main question is why Simplify or FullSimplify did not do it? May be my expectation of Simplify/FullSimplify was too much.

Comment: `f2 // TrigExpand // TrigReduce` also works, suggesting that `TrigReduce` would not work directly unless the expression has been expanded out previously. I don't know much about the inner workings of `Simplify`. Perhaps there is an option to get things moving.